# MakeOTF Installation on Ubuntu

Tags: python, libreoffice, fonts, adobe

If am interested in the installation of Source-Sans-Pro adobe font which can be procured from this location: https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans-pro

According to the documentation given on the page, this requires the `makeotf` CLI, for installing the fonts from source.

According to the Adobe website, https://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko.html, makeotf is part of AFDKO toolkit, which can be installed using `pip` as mentioned in https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/afdko.

However, the `makeotf` command is still not available on the shell.

PS: The source sans pro is available as OTF on github, but LibreOffice fails to recognise the OTF, and does not show it in the list of available fonts, even if `fc-cache -fv` is run both as an administrator and a user.

Answer (score 0):

Read the `README.md` file in the root directory of the afdko source tree. Install the necessary files. I setup a virtual environment using the First Install Option and obtained the necessary tools which were available in the virtual python environment: `makeotf`, `otf2ttf`, `ttfcomponentizer`...

I used these in the Sanssource master tree to build the fonts for both otf and ttf. The `build.sh` produced an error. So, I just build them one at a time based on the one example given in the `README.md` file. My python version was more recent than that mentioned in the docs. But it worked anyway.